# Kentico Tapping into Page Level Events

Tags: events, kentico

We are creating webevents in a DB other than Kentico. These webevents are then used for enterprise reporting. I need to implement the same inside Kentico project.

1. Is there an event that can fire after the page has loaded so that i can create my web event with page name and user information if logged in.
2. I have also seen in the past that with events, the Request and Session objects are not available. However, HTTPContext.Current is available. I need the Request and Session objects.

We are using **Kentico version 7.0.92 and have a portal template** site.

Now, i don't want to use portal template page to create events since this code executes multiple times with each request for a page.

Basically, i am interested in the PageName, Session and Request objects.

I have looked around [Kentico 7 documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?event_handlers_overview.htm). Looks like we have CMSRequestEvents but haven't been able to find sample code.

**Update:**
   Looks like the missing piece is [CMSContext class](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?cmscontext_class.htm). Now just trying to find the right event for CMSRequestEvents, where i have the Session object available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest modifying `Kentico\CMS\Global.asax.cs` in the following way:

```cs
public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();
    CMSRequestEvents.AcquireRequestState.After += AcquireRequestState_After;
}

void AcquireRequestState_After(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do your stuff...
}
```

By that time the `HttpContext.Current.Session` [should already be initialized](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307985/en-us#1). Page name can be retrieved from the `HttpContext.Current.Request` which should never be null.

Comment: Thanks for the info, once again.